# C++ Best way to create a new string from index of char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, indexing, char

I got a chars array like

```
char ch[] = "This is a char array";
```

and I want to make a new string from index n to index j, for i.e.

```
string str = stringFromChar(ch, 0, 5); //str = 'This'
```

Comment: `char[]  ch` this is not a valid syntax. maybe in C#, but not in C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the constructor for [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes two iterators.

```
std::string str(std::begin(ch), std::next(std::begin(ch), 5));
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/5bvkg)

In the more general case, you could use `std::next` for both the start and end iterator to make a string from an arbitrary slice of the array.

I prefer to use the C++ Standard Library when applicable, but know that you could do the same thing with pointer arithmetic.

```
std::string str(ch, ch+5);
```

Comment: BTW, what is diffrent between std::next(std::begin(ch), 5) and std::begin(ch)+ 5 ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi `std::next` and `std::advance` handle advancing through a container that may or may not use contiguous memory (i.e. a `std::list`, etc).

Comment: Oh my god I was always using  the + way and I thought that my code run for any container.. Foolish me!   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just write

```
string str(ch, ch + 5); //str = 'This'
```

That is the general form will look like

```
string str(ch + i, ch + j); //str = 'This'
```

where i < j

If the first index is equal to 0 then you can also write

```
string str(ch, n );
```

where n is the number of characters that you are going t0 place in the created object. For example

```
string str( ch, 4 ); //str = 'This'
```

Or if the first index is not equal to 0 then you can also write

```
string str( ch + i, j - i ); //str = 'This'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the constructor with iterators ( also, char* is a valid input iterator )

```
 std::string str(ch, ch + 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the **begin** and **end** functions...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() {

    char ch[] = "This is a char array";
    std::string str(std::begin(ch), std::end(ch));
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```